# Maximum value of a function given other conditions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g$ be a differentiable function on the interval $[a,\, b]$ with $g′(a) > 0$ and $g′(b)<0$. Prove that the maximum value of $g$ on $[a, b]$ is attained at a point $c \in (a,\,b)$ and deduce that $g′(c) = 0$.

What would be the best way to go about the proof? I was considering using the intermediate value theorem however we do not known if $g'$ is continuous.

Comment: Hint: apply the intermediate value theorem to the derivative

Comment: $g'(a)>0$ implies the maximum of $g$ can't occur at $x=a$. Similarly, the maximum of $g$ can't occur at $x=b$. $g$ does have a maximum, and since it occurs at an interior point, the derivative of $g$ has to be zero there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$g'(a)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+}{g(a+h)-g(a)\over h}=r>0.$$ For small positive $h$, then, $${g(a+h)-g(a)\over h}>r/2>0.$$ This implies there is a positive $h$ with $a+h<b$ and $g(a+h)>g(a)$.  So, the maximum value of $g$ on $[a,b]$ is not attained at $x=a$.

Using a similar argument, and the hypothesis that $g'(b)<0$, you can show the maximum value of $g$ is not attained at $x=b$.

$g$ indeed has a maximum value on $[a,b]$. From the above, it must be attained at a point $c\in(a,b)$. A well-known theorem (whose proof is essentially the above) implies $g'(c)=0$.